# jquery stop scrollTop animation if global variable counter is zero?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a global variable for a counter of 3 which works but I'd also like my scrollTo animation to stop working once the counter is 0. How do you stop the scrollTop animation if the hintCounter is zero?

JS below. I can add HTML if needed. Thanks!

```
// Limits hints to 3 and changes hint number and directions below it
var hintCounter = 3;

$('.itemList li').on('click', function() {
    if (hintCounter > 0) {
        hintCounter--;

        if (hintCounter == 0)
            $('.directions').addClass('bumpUp').html('Sorry you are all<br /> out of hints. <br />Keep Searching!');

        $('.xHints').html(hintCounter + ' Hints');
    }
})

// Scroll to top once a hint name is clicked
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#gameBoard").offset().top
}, 1000);

// Check to see if hintCounter is 0, if so do not animate ?
```

Comment: isn't the animate suposed to be inside the click function? also, that 'if (hintCounter == 0)' should be and 'else' of 'if(hintCounter>0)'?

Comment: It sounds like my syntax is off. I am still learning. Would you mind showing an example so I can see and learn from it? Thanks.

Comment: take a look at my answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess this should be the order of the actions, after reading your code and making some assumption.

```
// Limits hints to 3 and changes hint number and directions below it
var hintCounter = 3;

$('.itemList li').on('click', function() {
    // check if has hints
    if (hintCounter > 0) {
        hintCounter--;

        // Scroll to top once a hint name is clicked
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#gameBoard").offset().top
        }, 1000);

        $('.xHints').html(hintCounter + ' Hints');
    }else{
    // else show the message out of hints
        $('.directions').addClass('bumpUp').html('Sorry you are all<br /> out of hints. <br />Keep Searching!');
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh! I see! I needed to make an if else statement not if if! Thank you! This works. If I wanted another animation to stop once the three hints were used, would I only need to add a stop() in the else statement or would I need to include a reference to the animation in the if statement as well? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suposed your animation will only work if you click AND have hints, so I guess a stop is not necessary, unless you allow the player to click in several hints at the same time and don't want the animation to queue and play a lot of time, in that case, put an stop() before .animation()